# How to show superscript 2 in dropdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to show text as cm<sup>2</sup>(centimeter square) in drop down in my aspx page but its not showing as square. please suggest the code c#.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="5 cm2" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="15 cm2" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: yes but <sup>2</sup> not working in dropdown text.

Comment: do you mean `²` instead of `2`?

Comment: yes! but how to resolve this isssue plese suggest.

Comment: Copy from here and past there.

Comment: thanks but how could you type   cm² .

Comment: You have already typed it here, did you?

Comment: if we bind dropdownlist from database then how to put superscript.

Comment: well it should be `cm²` in your database too, however if its not you can replace "cm2" with "cm²" after you get it from db